# I want to display data from firebase in a tableView

Tags: ios, firebase

First Off I know this question has been asked but all the solutions I've tried hasn't worked. I want to take data from my firebase real-time database and put it into a tableView. My database is set up like this:

```
Clubs- 
  Club1- 
     Name- Club1 
     date- 5/09/18
```

In each tableView cell, I want to see my club name followed by the date. My code compiles fine but dosen't do anything.
My TableViewControllers Title is "Cell" but I don't have a reuse identifier on the tableViewCell.

```
//
//  CoolTable.swift
//  
//
//  Created by AISD on 4/2/19.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
var refa: DatabaseReference!

class CoolTable: UITableViewController{
    var posts = [eventStruct]()

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refa = Database.database().reference()
        loadNews()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self


    }
    struct eventStruct {
        let name: String!
        let date: String!
    }

    func loadNews() {
        refa.child("Club").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let name = valueDictionary["Name"]
                let date = valueDictionary["date"]
                self.posts.insert(eventStruct(name: name, date: date), at: 0)
                self.tableview.reloadData()


            }
        })
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].name



        let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].date

        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should give your cell a reuse identifier of "Cell" since that is what you're trying to get.
2. `numberOfRowsInSection` is asking for how many rows your table will have, in your case this should be `posts.count`.
3. In `numberOfSections` try just returning 1.
4. Finally, create a class for your TableViewCell to properly set the labels values. Simple explanation [here](https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e).